# Manifest Merger failed after implementing AndroidX dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, mvvm

I'm trying to build an app with the MVVM architecture and for that, I've implemented the following in my `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {

    def lifecycle_version = "2.0.0"
    def room_version = "2.1.0-alpha03"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
}
```

But then I got a `Manifest Merger Failed` error:

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-19:19 to override.
```

The stack suggested that I put `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"` to the `<application>` element in the Manifest but that in itself caused a bigger error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to use AndroidX, *all* of your support dependencies need to be AndroidX.

That includes `appcompat-v7` and `constraint-layout`.

AndroidX has a [migration table](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) which gives you all the support library equivalents.

This will require some manual migration, as certain imports (AppCompatActivity, ConstraintLayout, etc) will now be invalid. If you try to build, it'll tell you where these invalid imports are in the build error log.

Also make sure to find any uses you have of AppCompat Views in XML (like ConstraintLayout) and replace them with their AndroidX counterparts (just start typing in the View classname and Android Studio will suggest the proper one).

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem.  I upvoted you and accepted your answer.  If you think that this was a well asked question, could you kindly give me an upvote as well?

Answer (score 0):

TheWanderer is right.  I had to change everything into AndroidX and that's what I did.  Here is my new dependency:

```
dependencies {

    def lifecycle_version = "2.0.0"
    def room_version = "2.1.0-alpha03"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
}
```